# Omega Notation and Average Running Time Problem

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

if we have an algorithm that average running time of randomized algorithm A for input of size n is equal to $\theta(n^2)$.

why there would be an input data such that A solve it in $\Omega(n^{3n})$?

Answer (score 0):

Because $\Theta\left(n^2\right)$ is characterizing *average* running time across all possible inputs, - it just means that your algorithm runs extremely well on vast majority of inputs but has a small margin of pathological cases.

**EDIT** Note that in such a case, the *worst-case* complexity would be $\Omega \left(n^{3n}\right)$, but that does not contradict that *average-case* complexity is quadratic - you could be dividing by a large denominator when taking the average...

Comment: Thanks, you means if we say there is input that $O(n^n)$ is correct?

Comment: Why would there will be an input s.t. A solve it in $\Omega(n^{3n})$?
consider the random algorithm for sorting an array of size n:
in probability $0.5$ it uses bubble sort and in probability $0.5$ it uses max sort.

in any case the running time is $\Theta(n^2)$,as well in the average case

Comment: Dear @Snufsan, some of my friend say because the average case is $\theta (n^2) $ so there is no case that run in $\Omega (n^{3n}) $. because is bigger than $\theta (n^2) $

Comment: I don't understand what you mean but look at the following algorithm for sorting an array:

- toss $3nlogn$ coins, if all heads calculate somthing in $n^{3n}$ steps and then use bubble sort

- else use bubble sort

I think it will work for an example that satisfies what you want

Comment: Suppose there is an algorithm that average of running time is: $\theta (n^2) $. there would be any case that this algorithm solves one inputs in $O(n^n) $?

Comment: @MounaMokhiab yes, same method as Snufsan described in the above comment: toss $f(n)$ coins if all heads, waste $n^n$ time and do something in $n^2$, else do something in $n^2$. Total running time is $2^{-f(n)} n^n + (1-2^{-f(n)}) n^2$ and now if $f(n)$ is large enough you are good to go.

Comment: Dear @gt6989b, would you please add this example  to your answer?

Comment: Dear @Snufsan, Average case analysis gives an upper bound for the expected
running time of a single execution of a randomized algorithm
with a worst-case input.

Comment: it's a randomized algorithm, your answer is false.

Comment: @MounaMokhiab think about how you compute average-case running time for an algorithm. you compute what it's performance is on a set of all possible inputs and take the average. when you take the average, it may do bad on a *very small* section of inputs but do ok on the rest - since you are averaging over a *very large* quantity - it will take out any factor of your choice. Randomization was just a simplest way to give an example of this.

Comment: it's not related to amortized analysis ?

Comment: No relation between the two..